# PHP не работает проверка

Tags: php

```
    <?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Practice</title>

</head>
<body>
<?php 
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dblogin = "mysql";
$dbpass = "mysql";
$dbname = "Login";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dblogin,$dbpass);
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    "Failed to conect".$conn->connect_error();
}

 ?>
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="do_signup">
 </form>
<?php 
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($_POST['do_signup'])) {

$errors = array();
if (trim($data['name']) == '') {
    $errors[] = "Введите логин";
}
if ($data['pass'] == '') {
    $errors[] = "Введите пароль";
}
if (trim($data['email']) == '') {
    $errors[] = "Введите емаил";
}
if (empty($erorrs)) {
    $name = $data['name'];
    $pass = $data['pass'];
    $email = $data['email'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id,user_name,user_pass,user_email) VALUES (NULL,'$name','$pass','$email')";
$conn->query($sql);
}else{
echo "<div id='errors' style='color:red;'>".array_shift($errors)."</div>";
}} 
?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает проверка. Отправляет даже пустые значения

Comment: Не проще проверять на `empty()`?

Comment: Так просто читабельней

Comment: Попробуйте с `empty()`, уверен, что проблема как раз в этих условиях (`if ($data['pass'] == '')...`

Comment: Да есть теперь не отправляет, но еще одна проблема появилась, не выводит ошибки, можешь подсказать как исправить???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас опечатка if ( empty($erorrs ) ) вместо if ( empty($errors ) )

Comment: Все заработало, всем спасибо